# Authenticating users in a Symfony2 Application

Tags: php, symfony

This is going to sound very weird but kindly bear with me. I have built a symfony2 application which runs pretty well on the web.

Some users in the  field are having so much trouble accessing the application on their phones in the field because we all know how heavy symfony is. The situation is so bad i'm forced to heavily scale down their access to just a four page access with just three php files, 1  for authentication, one for data entry and one for viewing their entries, all these without using symfony2 but plain php.

Now to my question, how do i check password against database password/salt?

I'm using FOSUserBundle for security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using FOSUserBundle for security? [I think you'll find you're using the core SecurityBundle for that](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle#fosuserbundle). The way the user's password is stored will [depend on how you have configured the security system](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password).

The [MessageDigestPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php) is what is used to encode the passwords. From looking at that code you can replicated it as needed. The gist of it is merge the password and salt (`$password.'{'.$salt.'}'`) and then run it through PHP's hash function `hash($this->algorithm, $salted, true)` for however many iterations are needed.

Although, not specifically related to the question you asked, I'm a little confused as to what you mean by having to scale back the PHP for mobile users? Server page generation will take just as long for mobile as desktop users so why are you reimplementing outside of the symfony framework?

Comment: I'm serving the required pages through flat php without any hint of symfony whatsoever. The login will occur in login.php, form will be in add.php and listings will be in entries.php. All the other manipulation stuff will be left for desktop access

Comment: Yeah, I understood what you are doing I'm just question WHY you are doing it, that's all. But if it works that all that really matters ☺.

Comment: You should be able to determine the hash that's used by looking at your symfony security config file

Comment: I looked everywhere the has doesn't seem to make sense, that's where I need help with.

The reason is, in the field, the connection in random so most have Edge connectivity on their forms, symfony takes way to long to load under this connections to offer any effective form of service

Comment: This is the relevant part

encoders:
                "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512

Answer (score 1):

you can use user manager to check user credentials validity. i've created the following function for such mission.

```
/**
 * authorize user by username and password
 * 
 * @param string $username
 * @param string $raw_password
 */
public function authUserByUsernamePassword($username, $raw_password) {
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

    // username not found
    if (!$user) {
        throw new \Exception("User with username: $username not found!", 0);
    }

    $encoder_service = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');
    $encoder = $encoder_service->getEncoder($user);
    $encoded_pass = $encoder->encodePassword($raw_password, $user->getSalt());

    if($encoded_pass != $user->getPassword()){
        throw new \Exception("wrong password!", 0);
    }

    // Get UsernamePasswordToken
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles());
    // Set token
    $this->authUserByToken($token);

    return $this->getUserToken($user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer this but I'm looking for a non symfony solution. I'm using flat php eg login.php to authenticate and create session